# notepad not saving files

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I was making a php file using notepad in windows XP and was constantly making changes to the open instance of file and then saving it using ctrl + s.However after two to three modifications the changes were not saved automatically and I had to close that instance and open a new one.What was the reason for that???

Comment: Try open the notepad as admin and the open the .php file make modification save it

Comment: Do you get errors? And, did this happen only once or did the problem occur again later?